# ListFragment With Custom ArrayAdapter Scroll issue

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, fragment, adaptor

Hi I am new to Android/Xamarin Dev and i have a problem. I follow a example from [here](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/SlidingMenuSharp) . I have a ListFragment with Custom ArrayAdapter . I make it Like [this](http://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews) (ViewHolder) and when i scroll down my items get confused . What i mean is If i have a list with 5 items and one item has a textview with value 10 when i scroll down to the other items some item random get the value 10 , i debug step by step and my List/Array has not contain the value 10 and i cant find the source of the problem.

When i stop using this :

```
if (view != null)
{
    holder = view.Tag as MenuItemHolder;
}
```

I dont have the problem but i lack of performances.

P.S sorry for my english I am Greek and sorry for my bad Post i am new here :(

EDIT here is my code:
The problem in this is when i make holder.NumberTextView.Text +1 is ok but when i scroll +1 goes random to other items

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            MenuItemHolder holder = null;

            var view = convertView;

            if (view != null)
            {
                holder = view.Tag as MenuItemHolder;
            }
            if (holder == null)
            {
                holder = new MenuItemHolder();

                view =LayoutInflater.From(Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.rowWithButtons, null);
            holder.RemoveButton = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.DecreaseButton);
            holder.AddButton = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.IncreaseButton);
            holder.NumberTextView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.NumberTextView);
              holder.AddButton.Click += delegate
                {                        
                    holder.NumberTextView.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(holder.NumberTextView.Text) + 1).ToString();
                };

              holder.RemoveButton.Click += delegate
                {
                    if ((Convert.ToInt32(holder.NumberTextView.Text) > 1))
                    {
                        holder.NumberTextView.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(holder.NumberTextView.Text) - 1).ToString();
                    }
                };

           view.Tag = holder;

            }
           holder.Title.Text = GetItem(position).Name;




            return view;
        }


public class MenuItemHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
   public TextView Title { get; set; }

    public Button OptionsButton{ get; set; }

    public TextView NumberTextView{ get; set; }

    public  Button AddButton{ get; set; }

    public  Button RemoveButton{ get; set; }

    public Button DoneButton { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: If you can show your code then we may help yoj

Comment: why i got -1 ? I know my questions is hard to read but i cant do better right now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the you store the value in the NumberTextView, which is view in a holder. 
ViewHolder pattern improve performance in a way that you initialize view once, when holder is null. That means one instance of TextView(NumberTextView) draws all items in ListView. Thats why when you increase value and store it in NumberTextView you set the value to all list items. You don't see that immediately, because list is not redrawn. When you scroll and new list items are drawn to screen they have the same increased value.

The solution is to store the value for every list item somewhere else. Add the field to object that you obtain from GetItem method.

For example:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        MenuItemHolder holder = null;
        var view = convertView;
        YourItemClass item = GetItem(position);

        if (view != null)
        {
            holder = view.Tag as MenuItemHolder;
        }
        if (holder == null)
        {
            holder = new MenuItemHolder();

            view = LayoutInflater.From(Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.rowWithButtons, null);
            holder.RemoveButton = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.DecreaseButton);
            holder.AddButton = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.IncreaseButton);
            holder.NumberTextView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.NumberTextView);

            holder.AddButton.Click += delegate
            {                        
                item.increaseValue();
                holder.NumberTextView.Text = (item.Value).ToString();
            };

            holder.RemoveButton.Click += delegate
            {
                if (item.Value > 1))
                {
                    item.decreaseValue();
                    holder.NumberTextView.Text = (item.Value).ToString();
                }
            };

            view.Tag = holder;

        }
        holder.Title.Text = GetItem(position).Name;
        holder.NumberTextView.Text = (item.Value).ToString();

        return view;
    }


public override YourItemClass GetItem(int position) 
{
    if(listOfItems != null)
        return listOfItems.ElementAt(position); 
    return null;
}


class YourItemClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get;set; }

    public void increaseValue()
    {
        Value++;
    }

    public void decreaseValue()
    {
        Value--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your getView() method code of Adapter so i can filter out the actual problem.

Comment: Thank you so much @stofo89 ... Finaly i am starting to understand Android better.. have a nice day :)